# Is the author implicitly doing a proof by contradiction?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, natural-deduction

In Lang, Serge. "Basic Mathematics" (p.42), appears this proof:

> From the existence of an inverse for non-zero rational numbers, we deduce:
>   $$\text{If } ab=0, \text{then $a=0$ or $b=0$}$$
>   **Proof**. Suppose $a \neq 0$. Multiply both sides of the equation $ab=0$ by $a^{-1}$. We get:
>   $$a^{-1}ab=0a^{-1}=0.$$
>   On the other hand, $a^{-1}ab=1b=b$, so that we find $b=0$, as desired.

As I see it, the author is implicitly doing one of two options.

**Option 1**: he is adding $\forall x(x=0 \lor x \neq 0)$ as a premise and then using Law of Excluded Middle.

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall I} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I} \: #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
\def\ci#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ce#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land E} \: #1 \\}
\def\oi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor I} \: #1 \\}
\def\oe#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I} \: #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=I}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg I} \: #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
\def\x#1{\qquad\mathbf{X} \: #1 \\}
\def\DNE#1{\qquad\mathbf{DNE} \: #1 \\}
$

$
\fitch{
1.\,\forall x(x \neq 0 \to \exists y(yx=1 \land xy=1))\\
2.\,\forall x(x \in \mathbb{Q} \to 0x=0)\\
3.\,\forall x(x \in \mathbb{Q} \to 1x=x)\\
4.\,\forall x(x=0 \lor x \neq 0)
}{
\fitch{5.\, ab=0 \land a \in \mathbb{Q} \land b \in \mathbb{Q}}{
 6.\,a=0 \lor a \neq 0 \Ae{4}
 \fitch{7.\, a=0}{
   8.\,a=0 \lor b=0 \oi{7}
}\\
\fitch{9.\, a \neq 0}{
 10.\,a \neq 0 \to \exists y(ya=1 \land ay=1) \Ae{1}
 11.\,\exists y(ya=1 \land ay=1) \ie{10,9}
 \fitch{12.\, a^{-1}a=1 \land aa^{-1}=1}{
 13.\, a^{-1}a=1 \ce{12}
 14.\, a^{-1}ab= a^{-1}0 \qquad Leibniz(5)\\
 15.\,1b=0 \qe{13,14}
 16.\,b \in \mathbb{Q} \to 1b=b \Ae{3}
  17.\,b \in \mathbb{Q} \ce{5}
  18.\,1b=b \ie{16,17}
  19.\,b=0 \qe{18,15}
  20.\,a=0 \lor b=0 \oi{19}
}\\
21.\,a=0 \lor b=0 \Ee{11,12-20}
}\\
22.\,a=0 \lor b=0 \oe{6,7-8,9-21}
}\\
23.\,ab=0 \land a \in \mathbb{Q} \land b \in \mathbb{Q} \to a=0 \lor b=0 \ii{5-22}
24.\,\forall y(ay=0 \land a \in \mathbb{Q} \land y \in \mathbb{Q} \to a=0 \lor y=0) \Ai{23}
25.\,\forall x\forall y(xy=0 \land x \in \mathbb{Q} \land y \in \mathbb{Q} \to x=0 \lor y=0) \Ai{24}
}
$

**Option 2:** assuming $a \neq 0$, he sets up a proof by contradiction. If that is the case, I think this would be the proof.

$
\fitch{
1.\,\forall x(x \neq 0 \to \exists y(yx=1 \land xy=1))\\
2.\,\forall x(x \in \mathbb{Q} \to 0x=0)\\
3.\,\forall x(x \in \mathbb{Q} \to 1x=x)\\
4.\,\forall x(x=0 \lor x \neq 0)
}{
\fitch{5.\, ab=0 \land a \in \mathbb{Q} \land b \in \mathbb{Q}}{
\fitch{8.\, \neg(a = 0 \lor b=0)}{
 \fitch{9.\, a \neq 0}{
   10.\,a \neq 0 \to \exists y(ya=1 \land ay=1) \Ae{1}
 11.\,\exists y(ya=1 \land ay=1) \ie{10,9}
 \fitch{12.\, a^{-1}a=1 \land aa^{-1}=1}{
 13.\, a^{-1}a=1 \ce{12}
 14.\, a^{-1}ab= a^{-1}0 \qquad Leibniz(5)\\
 15.\,1b=0 \qe{13,14}
 16.\,b \in \mathbb{Q} \to 1b=b \Ae{3}
  17.\,b \in \mathbb{Q} \ce{5}
  18.\,1b=b \ie{16,17}
  19.\,b=0 \qe{18,15}
  20.\,a=0 \lor b=0 \oi{19}
  21.\,\bot \ne{8,20}
}\\
22.\ \bot \Ee{11,12-21}
}\\
23.\,a=0 \IP{9-22}
24.\,a=0 \lor b=0 \oi{23}
25.\,\bot \ne{8,24}
}\\
26.\,a=0 \lor b=0 \IP{8-25}
}\\
27.\,ab=0 \land a \in \mathbb{Q} \land b \in \mathbb{Q} \to a=0 \lor b=0 \ii{5-26}
28.\,\forall y(ay=0 \land a \in \mathbb{Q} \land y \in \mathbb{Q} \to a=0 \lor y=0) \Ai{27}
29.\,\forall x\forall y(xy=0 \land x \in \mathbb{Q} \land y \in \mathbb{Q} \to x=0 \lor y=0) \Ai{28}
}
$

Are these valid reasonings ?

What is the option the author is following, if any ?

Comment: It is a proof by cases. If $a=0$, nothing has to be proven. If $a\ne 0$, we can multiply $ab=0$ from left with $a^{-1}$ to get $b=0$ (The author makes it unnecessary more complicated). This is a direct proof, no proof of contradiction anywhere. But the author in fact uses that either $a=0$ or $a\ne 0$  which guarantees that no case is omitted.

Comment: I read it as using LEM. If $a=0$ then we can prove the disjunction. If $a \neq 0$ then by following this reasoning we can also prove the disjunction. By LEM this is all we need to check.

Comment: He is only assuming $a \neq 0$ because the case where $a=0$ is trivial.

Comment: Proof by contradiction would assume **both** $a$ and $b$ are non-zero.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: No; he is simply exploiting the equivalence of $P \lor Q$ with $\lnot P \to Q$.

Comment: You are right ! Thank you so much, @Mauro ALLEGRANZA. I could not find a way to understand what he was doing. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome :-)